# Changing Color of Text Based on Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to make a simple increase/decrease counter. When var n is < 0 it changes to red, and same for ==, but when its greater than it stays black..am i missing something?

```
var n = 0

function increase() {
    n = n + 1
    document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = n
    if (n > 0) {
        document.getElementById('num').style.color = '#013220'
    }
    else if (n < 0) {
        document.getElementById('num').style.color = '#ff0000'
    }
    else if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById('num').style.color = '#000000'
    }
}
```

no error messages.

Comment: If `n` starts at `0` and only increases, it will never be red. It will only ever be black or `#013220`

Comment: Your code works as it is. Only that `#013220` is quite near to `#000000`, maybe you just can't see the difference ..?

Comment: It may also never be `0` either, since the first run of `increase` will always add 1 to `n`, so `n` will never be `0` when `increase` is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a way to do it:

```js
var n = -2. // let me start with a negative number so we can see that color too

function increase() {
    n = n + 1;
    let color = '#000000'; // default color is black
    if (n > 0){
        color = '#CC0'; // yellow when n > 0 
    }
    if (n < 0){
        color = '#ff0000'; // red when n < 0 
    }
    const elem = document.getElementById('numWrapper')
    elem.innerHTML = n
    elem.style.color = color

}
```

```html
<div id='numWrapper'>-2</div>
<button onClick='increase()'>Increase</button>
```